# JAVA : Button not closing the tab it is associated with

Tags: java, swing, tabs

Below is the  [snapshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8cD2.png) . Here i pressed close button of tab no 3 but instead it is asking to save work of tab no 1

Below is the code from my file Tab.java

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.io.File;

    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
    import javax.swing.text.Element;

    public class Tab {
    JTextArea textArea, linesTestarea;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    JLabel label;
    final JButton button = new JButton("x");;
    boolean newFile;
    String filename, filepath;
    JPanel panel;

    public Tab(JTabbedPane tabbedPane) {
        this.tabbedPane = tabbedPane;
        newFile = true;
        filename = "untitled.txt";
    }

    public Tab addTab(boolean newBlankTab) {
        textArea = new JTextArea();

        setLineNumberProperty();
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN,    StaticVariables.fontSize));
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab(null, scrollPane);
        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(tabbedPane.getTabCount() - 1);
        tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(tabbedPane.getTabCount() - 1,
                addPaneltoTabs(new JPanel()));
        tabbedPane.setBackgroundAt(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex(),
                Color.lightGray);
        System.out.println("from add tab " + tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
        filepath = new File(filename).getAbsolutePath();
        if (newBlankTab)
            StaticVariables.openedfiles.add(filepath);
        textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                linesTestarea.setText(showLineNumber(textArea));
                setTabTitle();
                if (StaticVariables.unsavedfiles.contains(getFilePath()) == false) {
                    StaticVariables.unsavedfiles.add(getFilePath());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                linesTestarea.setText(showLineNumber(textArea));
                if (StaticVariables.unsavedfiles.contains(getFilePath()) == false) {
                    setTabTitle();
                    StaticVariables.unsavedfiles.add(getFilePath());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                linesTestarea.setText(showLineNumber(textArea));
                setTabTitle();
                if (StaticVariables.unsavedfiles.contains(getFilePath()) == false) {
                    StaticVariables.unsavedfiles.add(getFilePath());
                }
            }
        });
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(linesTestarea);
        return this;
    }

    public JPanel addPaneltoTabs(JPanel panel) {
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        filename = filename + tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println("from label" + tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
        label = new JLabel(filename);
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 5));
        panel.add(label);

        setTabButtonProperty();
        panel.add(button);

        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println(button.getParent().getParent()
                        .getComponent(0));
                button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1,
                        new Color(0.200f, 0.123f, 0.123f, .2f)));
                button.setFont(StaticVariables.btnEnteredFont);
                button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
                button.setFont(StaticVariables.btnExitedFont);
                button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (StaticVariables.unsavedfiles.contains(getFilePath())) {
                    String activeFilename = new File(getFilePath()).getName();
                    int opt = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, activeFilename
                            + " is not saved", "Sodalime Save files alert",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                            (Object[]) obj(), null);
                    if (opt == 0) {

                    } else if (opt == 1) {
                        removeTabs();
                    } else {
                        Tab temp = StaticVariables.tablist.get(tabbedPane
                                .getSelectedIndex());
                        FileAction fa = new FileAction();
                        fa.FileSaveaction(temp);
                        removeTabs();
                    }
                } else {
                    removeTabs();
                }

            }
        });
        return panel;
    }

    public void showTabList() {
        JPanel tabPanel = new JPanel();
        tabPanel.setSize(200, StaticVariables.tablist.size() * 10);
    }

    public String showLineNumber(JTextArea textArea) {
        int caretPosition = textArea.getDocument().getLength();
        Element root = textArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
        String text = "1" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        for (int i = 2; i < root.getElementIndex(caretPosition) + 2; i++) {
            text += i + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
        return text;
    }

    public void setTabButtonProperty() {
        button.setOpaque(false);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
        button.setToolTipText("close this tab");
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void setLineNumberProperty() {
        Dimension d = new Dimension(20, textArea.getHeight());
        linesTestarea = new JTextArea("1");
        linesTestarea.setPreferredSize(d);
        linesTestarea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(7, 0, 0, 1));
        linesTestarea.setEditable(false);
        linesTestarea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC,
                StaticVariables.fontSize));
        linesTestarea.setForeground(StaticVariables.linesColor);
    }

    public Object obj() {
        String options[] = { "Cancel", "close anyway", "Save and close" };
        return options;
    }

    public void removeTabs() {
        try {

            StaticVariables.openedfiles.remove(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
            StaticVariables.tablist.remove(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
            tabbedPane.remove(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setTabTitle() {
        this.label.setFont(StaticVariables.tabUnsavedTitleFont);
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return StaticVariables.openedfiles.get(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
    }
}
```

In the attached snapshot the selected tab is tab no 1, so due to the method getFilePath() whenever i press the close button it will return the index of the selected tab not the one the button is actually associated with. So how to make the button associated with tab no 3 actually close the tab no 3 ?

StaticVariables class contains following codes

```
    public class StaticVariables {

    public static int minWidth = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().width;
    public static int minHeight = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height;
    public static int menubarHeight = 150;
    public static int initialXcoordinates = 0;
    public static int initialYcoordinates = 0;
    public static int fontSize = 18;


    public static Color textareabgcolor = new Color(0.200f, 0.123f, 0.123f, .5f);
    public static Color linesColor = new Color(0.123f, 0.123f, 0.123f, .5f);

    public static ArrayList<Tab> tablist = new ArrayList<Tab>();
    public static ArrayList<String> unsavedfiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> openedfiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> fromOpenfile = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static Font btnEnteredFont = new Font("Times new Roman", Font.BOLD, 18);
    public static Font btnExitedFont = new Font("Times new Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18);
    public static Font tabUnsavedTitleFont = new Font("Times new Roman", Font.BOLD, 16);
    public static Font tabSavedTitleFont = new Font("Times new Roman", Font.PLAIN, 16);

}
```

This problem is setting my pace really slow, So if anyone needs full source Code it's on this [LINK](https://github.com/saurabdahal/sodalime-v1.0.git)

Comment: Despite being called `Tab`, this class seems to represent multiple tabs together. That, and the existence of a class called `StaticVariables`, are red flags that you might want to rethink your design. If you truly had a class that represented a single tab, it would be easier for you to associate its own button with closing that particular `Tab` instance.

Comment: @Riaz i have add code from StaticVariables class . Method addTab() returns the Tab class instance and it adds new tab to tabbedPane.

Comment: As you pointed out, the crux of the problem is the implementation of `getFilePath()`. My point is that if you had separation of concerns, each `Tab` instance concerned only with the items on that tab, each button would only know about its own tab and when clicked could fire off a `tabbedPane.remove(this)` or something similar, which will be cleaner and less error-prone than trying to coordinate indexes across multiple static variables.

Comment: ya I get your point. I will rewrite the code keeping in mind your suggestions, and let you know , thanks @Riaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the `JOptionPane` in wrong way. The dialog option creation parameter details can be read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29)-

For now as you have selected the YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, the arguments list you pass should be `new String[]{ "Label For Yes Button", "Label For No Button", "Label For Cancel Button" }`

Replace your hard-coded code with `JOptionPane` constants like below

```
if (opt == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
    //Do nothing
} else if (opt == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    removeTabs();
} else {
    Tab temp = StaticVariables.tablist.get(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
    FileAction fa = new FileAction();
    fa.FileSaveaction(temp);
    removeTabs();
}
```

You still will face the problem of `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. Make sure your `StaticVariables.tablist`, `StaticVariables.unsavedfiles`, `StaticVariables.openedfiles`, `StaticVariables.fromOpenfile` are consistent with current window state. Means they should contain the right value until the tab corresponding to them is visible and should not exist when the tab for them does not exists.

Comment: Thanks, edited my code according to your suggestion but still the problem I mention persists. any suggestions on solving that problem? it's killing me

Comment: I have tested your code. It works fine when you input some characters in each tab text area. Now if you try to close the tabs than it gives right output.

Comment: ya thanks but that's not the problem. On any text editor u can close any tabs u want even if that tab is not selected but on my editor it gives mentioned trouble. i want to be able to close the tab without selecting the tab and if some work is left unsaved on that tab then i want JOptionPane to display the name of the file opened on that tab . Hope my long explanation is not bothering You @Kamal Singh

Comment: I would like to underline few things. You should put the data in each `ArrayList` once the file is loaded or created new. Example: once user creates a new file, in `unsavedfileslist` its name will be registered. Once user clicks on save the data at the same index in `unsavedfilelist` should exist but it should have value `null` indicating that the file at this index is not needed to save. But once the tab is removed the data from each ArrayList maintaining the file state should also be adjusted by deleting the value as of the tab removed. Currently now what you do is update tbe array list only

Comment: when document has some changes. That is why when you feed some data in each text area of each tab, you get right results. Am I clear?

Comment: In my conversation the ArrayList refers to the multiple lists you are maintaining `public static ArrayList<Tab> tablist = new ArrayList<Tab>(); public static ArrayList<String> unsavedfiles = new ArrayList<String>(); public static ArrayList<String> openedfiles = new ArrayList<String>(); public static ArrayList<String> fromOpenfile = new ArrayList<String>(); `

Comment: Let me explain in detail :

Comment: You are explaining, or I have to explain?

Comment: Up untill this point everything works file .Now i create a new file and write something, when i am writing something the tab on which the textarea is , is selected so there is no problem but when i go back to first tab and click the close button on second tab , the popUp says untitled.txt is not saved instead of saying untitles2.txt is not saved. My whole problem whirls around this center point.

Comment: That is because you are relying on `getSelectedIndex()` method.

Comment: If you still have problem, let me know... I will help you

Comment: ya i know it's bad, so can you point out any way of getting the result without relying on getSelectedIndex()

Comment: If you like You can get the source code of my project on github  [link](https://github.com/saurabdahal/sodalime-v1.0.git)

Comment: Okay, I have got it. You can replace code to get the index of the current tab where the Close `X` button was pressed by replacing `int index = StaticVariable.tablist.indexOf(this)` and use `index` variable now. Let ne know if it helped....

Comment: Welcome!! My pleasure!!